# Extra Extension Added to Filename (PhP)

Tags: php

So after weeks of work, I have nearly perfected my image hosting service, however this is the only thing that I need to fix.

The below string just gets the filename, but I find that removing the [$i] on either end or removing certain parts of the string, the way the filename is handled will change.
Let's pretend that our file is named taco.png

```
$file_name[$i]=($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
```

This is what is currently working best. This results in taco.png.png, but I don't want the second .png, so I tried this.

```
$file_name=($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
```

After removing the first i, we get t.png, it just keeps the first letter, but the second .png is gone... yay?

```
$file_name[$i]=($_FILES['file']['name']);
```

Removing the second [$i] results in Array.png.

Anything else causes a syntax error.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you `var_dump($_FILES)` you'll see why.

Comment: It's because your `$_FILES` is a multi-dimensional array, meaning it looks like this: `Array( [0] => Array(), [1] => Array()....etc)`

Comment: @Darren Okay, so how do I change that? I'm a newer scripter and this was originally from a simple image hosting script which I have built from, I never touched the $_FILES Variable.

Comment: You would need to loop through as I presume this is in a `for`/ `foreach`/`while` loop? And actually create the names for each of the values.

Comment: Okay so as it turns out, the [$i] is pointless on both ends, I remove both of them and the script is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the following Html:

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" />
<input type="file" name="file[]" />
<input type="file" name="file[]" />
```

Then you should process it this way:

```
foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $filename) {
    //Work with $filename
}
```

---

Alternative you can do:

```
<input type="file" name="foo" />
<input type="file" name="bar" />
<input type="file" name="baz" />
```

And process it this way:

```
$fooFileName = $_FILES['foo']['name'];
$barFileName = $_FILES['bar']['name'];
$bazFileName = $_FILES['baz']['name'];
```

Comment: There is only one file upload field.

Comment: Then make `$_FILES['file']['name'][0]` but it should realy not an array in this case.

Comment: Adding the [0] just results in t.png again, unfortunately this still isn't the solution.

Comment: So what is `print_r($_POST)`?

Comment: Sure it is not in your code :D (It is a method for debuging)

Comment: Yeah ik, but in the past I've included debugs, all that print_r does on my page (yes, I inserted it correctly) is nothing.

Comment: If it is "nothing" you have not uploaded something.

Comment: woops. I uploaded the index.php to the wrong directory -_- hold on

Comment: For this situations i always echo `time()`. It always make sure i have the document, i expected ;)